# Multiplying matrices using pointers

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, matrix-multiplication

Hey guys I am trying practice learning pointers in c++.  So I am trying to multiply these arrays and am getting all 0's in my resulting matrix.  if anybody could just hint to me what to look at or some advice on what is causing this that would be amazing.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

/* Routines called. */
int loadMatrixFromFile(char *filename, int *data);
void showMatrix(int *data, int len);
int makeIdent(int matrixB[5][5], int length);
int matrixA[5][5];
int matrixB[5][5];
int matrixC[5][5];
void multiplyMatrices(int matrixA[5][5], int matrixB[5][5],int matrixC[5][5]);

int main(){
    int len, data[1000];
    len = loadMatrixFromFile("Numbers.txt", data);
    showMatrix(data, len);
    makeIdent(matrixB, len);
    multiplyMatrices(matrixA, matrixB, matrixC);
}

int makeIdent(int matrixB[5][5], int len){
    int i,j;
    int *ptr;
    ptr = &matrixB[5][5];
    printf("Matrix B is: \n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
           for(j=0;j<5;j++){
                 if(i==j){
                         *ptr=1;
                         printf("%d ", *ptr);
                 }
                 else{
                     *ptr=0;
                     printf("%d ",*ptr);
                 }
           }
           printf("\n");
     }
    return *ptr;
     printf("\n");
}
int loadMatrixFromFile(char *filename, int *data){
    FILE *in;
    int len;
    int j;
    in = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (in == NULL) {
        printf("Could not find file: %s \n", filename);
    }
    else {
        printf("Reading numbers...\n");
        fscanf(in, "%d", &len);
        printf("reading %d numbers from file %s ....\n", len, filename);
        for(j=0;j<len;j++) {
            fscanf(in, "%d", data + j);
        }
        fclose(in);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                matrixA[i][j] = *(data + i*5 + j);
        }
    }
    return len;
}
void showMatrix(int *data, int len){
    int j;
    int count = 0;
    printf("Showing %d numbers from data array....\n", len);
    printf("Matrix A is: \n");
    for(j=0;j<len;j++) {
        printf("%d ", *(data + j));
        count++;
        if(count % 5 == 0){
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void multiplyMatrices(int matrixA[5][5], int matrixB[5][5],int matrixC[5][5]){

     int i, n, j;
     int *ptr1, *ptr2, *ptr3;
     ptr1 = &matrixA[5][5];
     ptr2 = &matrixB[5][5];
     ptr3 = &matrixC[5][5];

     printf("\n");
     printf("Matrix A x Matrix B is: \n");
     for(i=0;i<5;i++){
         for(j=0;j<5;j++){
             *ptr3=0;
         }
     }
     for (i = 0; i<5; i++){
            for (j = 0; j<5; j++){
                for(n=0;n<5;n++){
                *ptr3 += (*ptr1**ptr2);
      }
                printf("%d ",*ptr3);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: In multiplyMatrices *ptr3=0; gets hammered a lot in a loop. Seems rather pointless.

Comment: In multiplyMatrices ptr[1-3] are all pointing to the end of the matrix! Yikes.

Comment: Oh, and you are never incrementing your pointers in multiplyMatrices.

Comment: how do you mean they are all pointing to the end of the matrix?  And I did the first loop in multiplyMatrices to initiate matricC to be all 0's.  Also how do i go about incrementing all 3 pointers?

Comment: The first loop in multiplyMatrices did not initialize C. Besides, you don't need to initialize C. C = A * B. Try my code below and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

In `makeIdent` you need to increment `ptr` after each element. To
initialize `ptr` you need to point it to the first element in the array, not the last element.

```
int makeIdent(int matrixB[5][5], int len){
    int i,j;
    int *ptr;
    ptr = &matrixB[0][0]; // note the 0 instead of the 5
    printf("Matrix B is: \n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
           for(j=0;j<5;j++){
                 if(i==j){
                         *ptr=1; 
                         printf("%d ", *ptr);

                 }
                 else{
                     *ptr=0;
                     printf("%d ",*ptr);
                 }
                 ptr++; // this is new
           }
           printf("\n");
     }
    return 0;
}
```

This is closer to what you want for multiplyMatrices:

```
void multiplyMatrices(int matrixA[5][5], int matrixB[5][5],int matrixC[5][5]){

 int i, n, j;
 int *ptr1, *ptr2, *ptr3;
 ptr1 = &matrixA[0][0];
 ptr2 = &matrixB[0][0];
 ptr3 = &matrixC[0][0];

 for (i = 0; i<5; i++) {
     for (j = 0; j<5; j++) {
         *ptr3 = (*ptr1 * *ptr2);
         ptr1++; ptr2++; ptr3++;
     }
 }
}
```

You could say this instead:

```
*ptr3++ = *ptr1++ * *ptr2++;
```

But I don't want to confuse the issue.

Comment: Hmm I tried that one.  It gives me a 5x5 matrix with all 0's except that [0][3] says 15746200.  Would that be the address that it is referring to for that index?

Comment: There are other issues in your code as well. makeIdent doesn't work for example.

Comment: makeIdent works for me when I compile it.  It displays the 5x5 identity matrix.  The issue I am having seems to be in that multiplyMatrices method

Comment: No, you think it works because of your print statements. Your print statements do not reflect what is being stored in the array. You need to move that 'ptr' through the array, not just point at one static place.

Comment: I see you've taught me a good deal about pointing the the beginning of the array instead of the end as well as incrementing the pointers and not just the rows and cols.  I am going to put some more effort into the multiplyMatrices and see if I can get it now.  I did change the makeIdent and of course you are correct :)

Comment: I'd suggest studying how arrays are laid out and how to move a pointer from the start of an array to the end of an array. In all of your code, you are never incrementing any of your pointers. Pointers do not automagically increment themselves inside your i and j loops.

Comment: Ok, I hope I was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37618/discussion-between-shawn-and-charlie-burns)