# error: invalid types ‘double[unsigned int]’ for array subscript

Tags: c++, c, pointers

**When I call the user defined function, I receive the following error:`*

```
    error: invalid types ‘double[unsigned int]’ for array subscript
       44 |    C[i][j]=0; 
    ...
```

**The user defined code**:

```
void Matrix(const double * A, const double *B, double * C){
    

   for(unsigned int i=0;i < 4;i++)    
    {    
        for(unsigned int j=0;j < 4;j++)    
        {    
            C[i][j]=0;    
                for(unsigned int k=0;k < 4;k++)    
                {    
                    C[i][j]+=A[i][k]*B[k][j];    
                }    
        }    
    }   
    

    
}
```

**Any help would be really appreciated.**

Comment: `C` is of type `double*`. Then `C[i]` is a `double`. Then `C[i][j]` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik double * C can't be used to define a matrix?

Comment: Well, as far as the C++ compiler is concerned, `double* C` is a pointer to an array of `double`s. If your code wants to interpret it as a matrix, it's up to that code to compute appropriate offsets into that array for each element.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  I understand, we are using pointer in C++

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> const double * A
> ```

This is a pointer to a `double` object.

> ```
> A[i]
> ```

This expression uses the subscript operator to indirect through the pointer. The resulting value is a sibling of the pointed `double` object in the same array of `double` objects.

> ```
> A[i][k]
> ```

This uses the subscript operator on the `double` object that you got from the first subscript operator. The language doesn't have such operator and as such the program is ill-formed. Same applies to your other pointers.

Comment: How to define such loops using  double * C ?

Comment: @BirdANDBird It's unclear what you mean by "such loops".

Comment: C[i][j]+=A[i][k]*B[k][j];

Comment: @BirdANDBird You cannot do that with a pointer to double, as I have explained in my answer. Therefore you cannot "define such loops" "using such pointer".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885170/multiplying-matrices-using-pointers

Comment: @BirdANDBird if you take a close look at the type of the MatrixA etc. in that code, you'll find that their type is not `double*` or even `int*`.